# Load new content from database when user scrolls to the bottom using jquery and php?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to load new content to my page from database when user scrolls to the bottom of a page. How this would be achieved? I've tought of jquery's ajax and php combined, but I have no idea.

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

Comment: OK, that's wordpress, and I've never even looked at wordpress code, so I'm unable find what code I need and what I don't.

Comment: That have a jQuery plugin too, check at the bottom of that page. or here http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for any plugin i gues. 
jQuery code for this

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
      //Add jQuery ajax code here to fetch data from server/database and append more elements etc
   }
});
```

Comment: And that jquery ajax code would be? I've only used jquery ajax once, and that was a form submit tutorial.

Comment: you would send request to your php page which will give back you result in result variable.  $.post("your_page.php",{data:txt},function(result){
    $("div").html(result);
  });

Comment: @ABC +1, You can even mimic the ajax call in the fiddle, check this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/2LdvT/3/